# How to add firebase analytics in xcframework iOS

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

Unable to create xcframework successfully with firebase analytics, it gives undefined symbol.

I also create demo project for iOS firebase analytics works fine for that but when I create xcframework with firebase analytics than can't fetch its logEvent.

Want to create xcframework with firebase analytics

Answer (score 0):

You can use this framework to integrate Firebase analytics.
Framework link:

- https://github.com/MehreenWaqar/FirebaseAnalytics.git

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).